# Spring Boot Security not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am creating a spring boot project with many micro services. My project consists of an Api Gateway(Zuul) a discovery service (Eureka) and two other micro services (Users and Accounts).

On the Gateway service I have implemented Spring Boot Security like this:

WebSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public WebSecurity(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"users-ws/users/status/check").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/createUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),environment));


    }
}
```

Authorization Filter

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

Environment environment;
AuthenticationManager authManager;


public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager,Environment environment) {
    super(authManager);
    this.environment = environment;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    chain.doFilter(request,response);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (authorizationHeader == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.replace("Bearer","");

    String userId = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(environment.getProperty("token.secret"))
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody()
            .getSubject();

    if (userId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId,null, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

}

So according to this everything should be authenticated except the first four urls right?

Because now it giving me this on all urls that according to my configurations should not need authentication

[image]

```
     2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/users-ws/users/status/check'; against 'users-ws/users/status/check'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/h2-console/**'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/createUser'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/login'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.214 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/users-ws/users/status/check'; against '/logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthorizationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6910dd88: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users-ws/users/status/check at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /users-ws/users/status/check; Attributes: [authenticated]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6910dd88: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2019-10-13 15:00:55.215 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@603b97b3, returned: -1
2019-10-13 15:00:55.216 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.apigatewayservice.apigatewayservice.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@46c5ddf9
2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against 'users-ws/users/status/check'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.217 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/h2-console/**'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/createUser'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST users-ws/users/login'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthorizationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6910dd88: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.218 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2019-10-13 15:00:55.219 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2019-10-13 15:00:55.222 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2019-10-13 15:00:55.222 DEBUG 34683 --- [nio-8011-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
2019-10-13 15:00:55.895  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2019-10-13 15:00:55.916  INFO 34683 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
```

Comment: Post your spring security debug logs please

Comment: I have just posted it. Thanks

Comment: @ChristosChadjikyriacou Hi. Im pretty sure you have to begin your URL with a slash '/'. Every character after the '192.168.1.110:8011'. You can begin by correcting that :). Lemme know if it helped

Comment: @Merv do you mean like this .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/users-ws/users/status/check").permitAll() ? I tried it and its the same :/

Comment: @ChristosChadjikyriacou yes. Then I have no idea. maybe if you post your project online we can take a look at it. But atleast your URL's are correct now. BTW did you remove all URL's and set permitall to instead of authenticated.

Comment: can you please post your full logs, i want to look at what caused the "AccessDeniedException"

Comment: The logs you posted are related to another request.  Request 'POST /users-ws/users' doesn't match 'GET /users-ws/users/status/check'

Comment: @ChristosChadjikyriacou Attach related logs. You posted logs for different request. Also what is your `AuthorizationFilter`? Add the code of that class. As 403 is related to Authorization you are hididng your implementation related  to Authorization in your post. So add `AuthorizationFilter` code.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! @Patel Romil answer worked! I don't know why though. Thanks eveyone for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add endpoints in `configure(WebSecurity web)` where you do not need to authenticate the user.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"users-ws/users/status/check")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/h2-console/**")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/createUser")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/login");

        //completely bypass the Spring Security Filter Chain.
    }
```

**WebSecurity.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public WebSecurity(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
              .ignoring()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"users-ws/users/status/check")
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/h2-console/**")
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/createUser")
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"users-ws/users/login");

            //completely bypass the Spring Security Filter Chain.
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),environment));
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this, will remove the role based access to pages right ?